# Controller's URL in Area is too long, how to shorten URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am new to Area term in MVC and I want to use it. I have the following directories that points to the controller in Area.

```
Areas > Admin > Controllers > AdminController
```

When I want to visit the Index Action of AdminController, I need to visit  http://localhost/Admin/Admin. I want to get rid of the second "Admin". I want to type http://localhost/Admin/ only. How can I do that?

AdminAreaRegistration.cs has the following MapRoute

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Give a default controller - `new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }` (but kind of defeats the purpose of having areas if you then have a controller of the same name within it)

Comment: it worked, thanks. But, I dont get it. When you put "new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }", does it mean that you specify that default controller is Admin?

Comment: Yes exactly - if the url is `.../Admin` it will match your `"Admin_default",` route (it starts with "Admin"). Because you did not provide a 2nd segment (for the controller) it will use the default values for the controller and action (in effect its the same as `.../Admin/Admin/Index`)

Comment: But as I noted, having a `AdminController` in a `Admin` area does not really make sense

Comment: thats a good point.Should I rename my controller to HomeController?

Comment: That would make a lot more sense :) (and with you current implementation if you wanted to navigate to another method in `AdminController` the url would be `.../Admin/Admin/AnotherMethod` which is probably not what you want

Comment: When I renamed it, It says Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'Home'. I should add namespaces I guess

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128494/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-ayilmaz).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not specified a default value for the controller so unless you include it in the url, the routing engine has no way it identify which controller you want to navigate to.  You can solve this by giving a default value for the controller name

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Admin_default",
    "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

While that means that `../Admin` will navigate to the `Index()` method of `AdminController`, it still means that if you want to navigate to another method in `AdminController`, your url will need to be `../Admin/Admin/AnotherMethod` which is probably not what you want.

The purpose of areas is to logically group your controllers and methods. For example a shopping cart app might have a `ProductsController` where users might navigate to `../Product` to display a list of products or `../Product/Details/1` to display details of a product. But the app might need other methods for suppliers to create and edit their products so you would create a separate `Suppliers` area where `../Suppliers/Products` would navigate to their list of products, and `../Suppliers/Products/Edit/1` would allow them to update details of their product.

Having a `AdminController` in a `Admin` area does not really make sense, and I suggest that it should be `HomeController` if it contains general methods associated with admin tasks (and the route definition would then be `new { controller = "Home", .. }`